# Add multiline commit when using rebase in git

Tags: git

I want to change my single line commits to multiline commits adding more details. I tried using `git rebase -i` which opens up a file in nano where I can `reword` my commits. However, adding multiple line commits there doesn't work.

Comment: What does *does not work* mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Editing the commit message in the file with the list of commits does not do anything anyway, the commit messages are only there to identify the commits by more than the SHA.

If you selected the `reword` stanza for a commit and continue, then when the commit in question is applied, your commit editor (nano in your case) opens with the commit message just like when you commit normally and you can put any commit message in there.